# Alternative single word for "in demand"?

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

Is there any alternative single word for the phrase "in demand"?

Because I couldn't find the word *demandable* as an adjective in any dictionary. The word *demanding* means strenuous.

For example:

> This car is ***demandable*** (incorrect, "demandable" doesnt exist)
>
> This car is ***in demand*** (correct)

Also:

> A ***demandable*** car (incorrect, "demandable" doesnt exist)
>
> A car ***in demand*** (correct)

Comment: Something that is in demand is not _demanding_, it is **demanded**. Another option is **popular**. Please tell us _how_ you want to use the word you are looking for (and I am also interested why you cannot use _in demand_... it's not that long?)

Comment: Please edit you question with this information, so people don't have to go through the comments to find it :)

Answer (score 2):

Try *1) [sought-after](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/sought-after?r=66), 2) [(much-)desired](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/desired)* and *3) [coveted](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/coveted?s=t)*.

> 1) Sought-after (adjective)
>   that is in demand; desirable:
>   *a sought-after speaker.*
>
> (Link and definition from dictionary.reference.com)
>
> 2) Desired (adjective)
>   wished for   *⇒ You may find that just threatening this course of action will produce the desired effect.   ⇒ His warnings have provoked the desired response.   ⇒ The plan failed to achieve the desired result.*
>
> (Link and definition from collinsdictionary.com)
>
> 3) Covet (verb)
>   2. to wish for, especially eagerly:
>   *He won the prize they all coveted.*
>
> (Link and definition from dictionary.reference.com)